# Das Wort "freihändig": Falscher Freund mit Englisch "freehand"?

Tags: adjective, meaning

Das Wort ***"freihändig"*** hat viele Bedeutungen. Es ist ganz schwer die sehr speziellen Bedeutungen zu verstehen, z.B. mit *"by private contract [comm.] [econ.]"* ([Leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=freih%C3%A4ndig)). Ich denke, es hat nichts mit dem Wort *"bereitwillig"* zu tun, ein Adjektiv vom Wort *"bereit"*, d.h. *"without hesitation"*. Dann:

> 1. Wie kann man das Wort "freihändig" benutzen? Welche Bedeutungen gibt es?
> 2. Gibt es Ähnlichkeiten mit dem Wort "freehand" auf Englisch? Das *"Freihandzeichnen"* ist aber etwas anderes, oder?
> 3. [Linguee](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=freih%E4ndig) zeigt, dass es auch ein juristisches Fachwort ist, nicht so im Englischen. Also wäre das ein "falscher Freund". Gibt es noch mehr solche "falsch-freundige" Bedeutungen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Freihändig bedeutet vor allem "ohne die Hände zu gebrauchen in einer Situation, in der man sie normalerweise benutzt". Ich kann zum Beispiel freihändig Fahrrad fahren. In diesem Sinne würde ich "freihändig" als "hands-free" übersetzen (allerdings ist ein "hands-free kit" eine "Freisprechanlage").

Freihändig im ökonomischen Sinn kommt vermutlich daher, dass i.A. Privaten die Hände nicht gebunden sind wenn sie einen Vertrag mit dritten abschliessen wollen, im Gegensatz zum Staat, der Aufträge öffentlich ausschreiben muss.

Für "freehand" im Sinne von "Freizeichnen" würde ich nicht "freihändig" benutzen. Insofern sind "freehand" und "freihändig" falsche Freunde.

Comment: Auf Englisch ist das Überzetzung doch `"direct"`, guckt in Linguee, aber es gibt besondere Situationen es zu benutzen, sowie Gesetz und Ökonomie. Ein ganzes speffizielles Wort aber `"freehand"` klingt nicht auf Englisch officiel so auf dieser Weise falsche Freunde, ja? +1

Comment: @hhh: ja, genau.

Answer (score 2):

In verschiedenen Bänden des *Duden* findet man für das Adjektiv *[freihändig](http://www.duden.de/node/661689/revisions/1334324/view)* drei grundlegend unterschiedliche Bedeutungen:

> 1. *ohne technische Hilfsmittel ausgeführt:*
>    freihändiges Zeichnen
>    englisch: freehand drawing; draw freehand
> 2. *ohne sich aufzustützen ausgeführt; ohne Zuhilfenahme der Hände:*
>    freihändig schießen; freihändig Rad fahren
>    englisch: offhand shooting; shoot offhand; cycle without holding on
> 3. (Amtssprache) *ohne öffentliche Versteigerung oder Ausschreibung; unter der Hand getätigt:*
>    ein freihändiger Verkauf
>    englisch: private sale; sell privately

Die erstgenannte und im Allgemeinen sicherlich häufigste Bedeutung von *freihändig* entspricht tatsächlich dem englischen Adjektiv bzw. Adverb *freehand*. Diesbezüglich ist diese Übersetzung also kein falscher Freund. Für die anderen Bedeutungen von *freihändig* sind allerdings je nach Zusammenhang ganz andere englische Übersetzungen möglich. Das gilt auch für den sehr speziellen juristischen und betriebswirtschaftlichen Fachbegriff *freihändiger Verkauf*.

Comment: Wo bitte wird "freihändiges zeichnen" öfters verwendet als "freihändig radfahren"? :-P